# Using redundant JSdoc in TypeScript docblocks. Is it needed?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

```js
export class FooClass {

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * A description
   *
   * @memberOf FooClass
   */
  barMethod(): Observable<Baz[]> {
    return this.http.get<Baz[]>(this.infoService.apiURL + '/bazs');
  }
}
```

So, I'm wondering if adding `@memberOf Class` documentation in TypeScript is useful.

Searching on Google I found this as the first result: https://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html. The problem is that this website returns a `Server Not Found` error and the documentation I found so far is very outdated.

In my humble opinion using `@memberOf` adds just noise in the codebase. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that just using TypeScript makes multiple (many? most?) JSDoc tags redundant and definitely in the example you've provided.

Comment: Is there any official spec for the TypeScript documentation? An official style guide?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm still looking for a complete style guide for using TSDoc. Do you know where to find it?